# How many positive integers $x \le 3600$ are there such that $\gcd(3600, x)=9$?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization

I'm trying to answer this question which has a hint: think about $\mathbb Z_{3600}$.

I tried to set up a linear equation,$\mod{3600},$ without any success. Not even the factorization of $3600$ gives me any ideas on how to set the problem.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$\gcd(3600,x)=9\Longrightarrow x=9y\quad,\quad y\in \Bbb Z_{400}\to \gcd(400,y)=1$$therefore **the number of solutions of $\gcd(3600,x)=9$ on $\Bbb Z_{3600}$ is equal to number of solution of $\gcd(400,y)=1$ on $\Bbb Z_{400}$ which is $\phi(400)$.**

Answer (score 0):

**A (different) hint**: notice that

$$ \gcd(3600,x) = 9 \iff \gcd(400,x/9) = 1.$$

Comment: Not true. You mean $\gcd(400,x/9)=1$ (and $x$ has to be a multiple of $9$).

Comment: @TonyK Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Such a number must be of the form $9k$, where $k\le 400$ and $\gcd(400,k)=1$.